# Why do my div's not line up?

Tags: html, css

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mxevk9q6/). I have a div with an img in it and another div with no image meant to be a placeholder but they don't line up. My html shows all the div's halfway down except the last. The [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mxevk9q6/) shows the problem but it doesn't look as bad.

Html:

```
<div class="profile-pics">
    <div class="pic-thumb-box"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EclNgPI.jpg" class="pic-thumb" /></div>
    <div class="pic-thumb-box"><span class="pic-thumb"></span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile-pics {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top
}
.pic-thumb-box {
    width:  250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.pic-thumb {
    width:  240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Declare a `vertical-align: top;` rule to the `.pic-thumb-box` class.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is that your `.pic-thumb-box` elements are containing `.pic-thumb` elements of different types. Your `<img>` element is going to behave as an `inline-block` display by default, but the `<span>` element will behave as an `inline` display. This prevents the `.pic-thumb` class from applying width and height to the `<span>` element. If you add `display: inline-block;` to your `.pic-thumb` class as suggested in another answer, you'll be able to apply height and width to your `<span>` element and fix your misalignment.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the space around your img, you could add "display: inline-block;" to the class .pic-thumb.

```
.pic-thumb {
    width:  240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/mxevk9q6/2/

Regards Andy

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your .pic-thumb{....}.
That will fix it